# Move the position in JEditorPane

Tags: java, jeditorpane

I've a JEditorPane inside a JDialog. I'm loading a web page when this JDialog is loading.
This web page is larger then the JEditorPane size. So I want to display a certain position in the web page by default.

For example, I've a 175x200 size jdialog and JEditorPane. I want to display the web page content around 150 pixels down.

Is there any solutions for this? Or is there any other component which I can used to display web pages and can move to a certain position of the web page at loading time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, if you don't want scroll bars (personally I think Pace has the best answer in that you should just show the scroll bars and scroll it to visible) would be to use the JViewport by itself:

```
    JViewport viewport = new JViewport();
    viewport.setView(editor);
    viewport.setViewPosition(new Point(0, 150));
    viewport.setViewSize(new Dimension(175, 200));
    viewport.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 200));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `JEditorPane` inside of a `JScrollPane`.  You could then grab the scrollbars from the `JScrollPane` and adjust them percentage-wise.  If you need to adjust them pixelwise then you can calculate the percentage you need to move by comparing the pixels you need to move with the total size of the `JEditorPane`.  You should be able to adjust the UI of the `JScrollPane` so the scroll bars aren't visible.

Comment: Can you say, which property in JScrollPane to use to adjust this?